# Excel IF -eq "Something" write in next available blank space

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I'm having a little trouble writing a formula that will populate the next available blank cell if statement is True.

If Column G equals "#Number" then write "This Equals #"... But I only want "This Equals #" on one cell, not all 4 (A1; A2; A3; A4).
Also, if 'A1' already contains "Something" write on 'A2'

Columns: A; B; C; G

A:

```
=IF(G1="#1","This Equals 1",IF(G1="#3","This Equals 3",IF(G1="#5","This Equals 5",IF(G2="#1","This Equals 1",IF(G2="#3","This Equals 3",IF(G2="#5","This Equals 5",IF(G3="#1","This Equals 1",IF(G3="#3","This Equals 3",IF(G3="#5","This Equals 5",IF(G4="#1","This Equals 1",IF(G4="#3","This Equals 3",IF(G4="#5","This Equals 5"))))))))))))
```

B:

```
=IF(G1="#2","This Equals 2",IF(G1="#4","This Equals 4",IF(G1="#6","This Equals 6",IF(G2="#2","This Equals 2",IF(G2="#4","This Equals 4",IF(G2="#6","This Equals 6",IF(G3="#2","This Equals 2",IF(G3="#4","This Equals 4",IF(G3="#6","This Equals 6",IF(G4="#2","This Equals 2",IF(G4="#4","This Equals 4",IF(G4="#6","This Equals 6"))))))))))))
```

C:

```
=IF(G1="#7","This Equals 7",IF(G1="#8","This Equals 8",IF(G1="#9","This Equals 9",IF(G2="#7","This Equals 7",IF(G2="#8","This Equals 8",IF(G2="#9","This Equals 9",IF(G3="#7","This Equals 7",IF(G3="#8","This Equals 8",IF(G3="#9","This Equals 9",IF(G4="#7","This Equals 7",IF(G4="#8","This Equals 8",IF(G4="#9","This Equals 9"))))))))))))
```

These are the current Results: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7trYF.jpg)
It should look like: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm8e2.jpg)

Shouldn't matter what order the numbers are added on Column G but should still populate the next available cell.
Maybe this can't be done using excel formulas? This is what I'm trying to figure out. Please let me know if what I'm asking makes sense or if further clarification is needed.

Essentially, the "#" represents a code/product number and the 3 columns represent categories.

Comment: I recommend learning VBA :P

Comment: More general question - why are you using that formula? Without a sample of your input and expected output, it looks like you could do a single formula instead? `="This equals " & SUBSTITUTE(G1,"#","")`?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  If A1 already has a value and G1 changes you want A1 to stay the same and the new value to go into A2, then if G1 changes again A2 remains the same and the new value goes into A3 and so on?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my description. Hopefully my edit makes more sense for what I'm try to accomplish. If further clarification is needed, please let me know - I'll do my best to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1:

```
=IFERROR("This Equals " & SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($G:$G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G$1:$G$4)/(($G$1:$G$4="#1")+($G$1:$G$4="#3")+($G$1:$G$4="#5")),ROW(1:1))),"#",""),"")
```

B1:

```
=IFERROR("This Equals " & SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($G:$G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G$1:$G$4)/(($G$1:$G$4="#2")+($G$1:$G$4="#4")+($G$1:$G$4="#6")),ROW(1:1))),"#",""),"")
```

C1:

```
 =IFERROR("This Equals " & SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($G:$G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G$1:$G$4)/(($G$1:$G$4="#7")+($G$1:$G$4="#8")+($G$1:$G$4="#9")),ROW(1:1))),"#",""),"")
```

then copy those formula down.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! 
Thanks for the quick turn-around time and for this formula!!
It's very much appreciated, sir.

Comment: Do not change the question after getting an answer, ask a new question.